# System.loadLibrary in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, abbyy

I'm currently trying to load a library in my project which I need to check a certain license I'm using. However when executing it just gives an error on the system.loadLibrary.

I'm using Android Studio and I've got the library placed in my libs folder and I already added it into my dependencies.

Code :

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.v( TAG, "onCreate()" );
    super.onCreate();

    //Gives the error.
    System.loadLibrary( "MobileImagingEngine" );
    try {
        Log.v( TAG, "MILicenser.getVersionInfo(): " + MILicenser.getVersionInfo() );
        final InputStream licenseStream = getAssets().open( "thelicense.License" );
        MILicenser.setLicense( licenseStream, "Android_ID" );
        Log.v( TAG, "MILicenser.setLicense() succeeded. " + MILicenser.getLicenseInfo() );
    } catch( final Exception exception ) {
        Log.e( TAG, "MILicenser.setLicense() failed", exception );
    }
    MIContext.createInstance();
}
```

Log :

```
Process: docspro.nl.docsproscanapp, PID: 10348
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load MobileImagingEngine from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/docspro.nl.docsproscanapp-8.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/docspro.nl.docsproscanapp-8]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
        at docspro.nl.docsproscanapp.MIApplication.onCreate(MIApplication.java:24)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4581)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1325)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Gradle file (Tried a solution from stack):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "project.name"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('lib/armeabi-v7a/libMobileImagingEngine.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/MobileImagingEngine.jar')
    compile files('libs/MobileImagingEngine_Doc.jar')
}

task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from(new File('libs')) { include '**' }
    into new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(buildDir, 'native-libs'))
}
```

Comment: Open the apk as a zip file and see if there is a corresponding libMobileImagingEngine.so in an architecture appropriate directory thereof.  If not, figure out why not.  Do you build this from source? Is it supplied prebuilt by a vendor?

Comment: It is a library that is prebuilt, it is given when purchasing a certain product. And it does not contain an .do file.

Comment: .so (the original of my comment suffered from an Android keyboard)

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: Gradle added. Plus there is no .so file

Comment: If there's no .so file in the apk you need to figure out where it was supposed to come from.  If you don't have an .so anywhere you either need to build it from source or you got an incomplete handoff from your vendor.

Comment: Is there any workaround? Like unzip the .jar and try adding it as an module or something? What I don't get is that I'm using it as a normal library in my dependencies, but when I try to load it it just wont load. However in Eclipse it used to load. So my clue is that the path might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was stuck on this problem couple of days ago. Just had to add a folder called "jniLibs" in my applications folder and Android Studio tok care of the rest.

For more info on using native libs
http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

Answer (score 0):

Project Structure->Facet, in structure tab, there is a row "Native libs directory". I think you should change it.

Comment: I dont have that row. Its just Libraries and Module Dependecies.

Comment: So, you are using gradle. Can you add gradle script?

Comment: I've added the gradle file. Note that I tried a solution from stack.

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed that you specified the following path in Dependencies: 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libMobileImagingEngine.jar'
In the MI SDK distribution libMobileImagingEngine.so is on the Android/Lib/armeabi-v7a folder, not libMobileImagingEngine.jar.

Please double check if all paths are specified correctly in the application.

In case it was not helpful please send us to SDK_Support@abbyy.com the following information for further investigation:

1.   The full project in order we could check all the settings on our side.

2.  Please specify whether the issue occurs on real device or simulator?

3.  Also please specify the Android version and the number of MI SDK build.